# Закрыть доступ к приложению определенной роли RBAC. Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Шаблон приложения: `advanced`
У меня 2 приложения: backend и frontend.

Мне необходимо, чтобы в backend имели доступ все роли, кроме `client`.

Я написал следующее в main.php:

```
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'controllers' => ['site'],
            'actions' => ['login'],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => false,
            'roles' => ['client'],
        ],
    ],
    'denyCallback' => function () {
        return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);
    },
],
```

В итоге получаю ошибку: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Как я понял все происходит так:

1. Пользователь заходит на site/login.
2. Авторизуется в системе. У него роль `client`. Доступ запрещен.
3. Идет редирект на site/login.
4. Пользователь уже авторизован. И у него роль `client`. Доступ запрещен.
5. См. 3

Бесконечный редирект...

Как этого избежать и закрыть доступ?

Comment: Вы ведь сами указали ему идти на `site/login` в случае если запрещен доступ - `denyCallback`. Уберите обработку, посмотрите что будет. Ну или, разлогиньте пользователя и верните на страницу авторизации. Или отобразите ему страницу что ему запрещено посещение.

Answer (score 1):

Просто проверяйте авторизацию пользователя в denyCallback:

```
'denyCallback' => function () {
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest()) {
        return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);
    } else {
        return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/error']);
    }
},
```